# If a matrix is such that its inverse is equal to its transpose, does it belong to the special orthogonal group

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification, proof-explanation, orthogonal-matrices

I'm trying to solve 3 problems on special orthogonal groups, and I need proof verification of the first 2 and help with the proof of the 3rd.

Consider $SO(n)$ the set of all $n \times n$ matrices with determinant equal to 1:

1. Show that If $A \in SO(n)$ then $A^{-1} \in SO(n)$

> Resolution:
>
> $A \in SO(n) \implies det(A) = 1$
>
> $A \times A^{-1} = I \implies det(A \times A^{-1}) = det(I) = 1$
>
> $det(A^{-1}) = 1 \implies A^{-1} \in SO(n)$

2. Show thatIf $A, B \in SO(n)$, then $AB \in SO(n)$

> Resolution:
>
> $A, B \in SO(n) \implies det(A) = det(B) = 1$
>
> $det(AB) = det(A) \times det(B) \implies det(AB) = 1 \implies AB \in SO(n)$

2. If $A^{-1} = A^T$, then $A \in SO(3)$?

> Resolution:
>
> This is were I'm stuck...

If anybody could point me in the right direction I would be extremely grateful.

Thanks!

Comment: "If $A^{-1} = A^T$, then $A \in SO(3)$."  Doesn't that just mean that $A \in O(3)$, not necessarily in $SO(3)$?

Comment: Sorry, the problem was incorrect. I edited the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answers to the first two questions are correct. For $3)$ remember that (for a square matrix) $\det A^T=\det A$ and use $A^TA=I \rightarrow (\det A)^2=1$. what you can say from this?